# Array column and aggregation in BigQuery SQL: Why the values are not all aggregated?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've executed the code below in BigQuery

```
SELECT ( --inner query
         SELECT STRING_AGG(c) FROM t1.array_column c
       ) 
FROM (
        select 1 as f1, ['1','2','3'] as array_column
        union all
        select 2 as f1, ['5','6','7'] as array_column
) t1;
```

I expected something like

```
Row|f0_
1  | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

because there is no `GROUP BY` in the inner query. So, I'm expecting `STRING_AGG` to be evaluated on all the lines.

`SELECT STRING_AGG(c) FROM t1.array_column c`

Instead I'm getting something like this:

```
Row|f0_
1  |1,2,3
2  |5,6,7
```

I'm having troubles understand why I have this result

Comment: Your "inner query" is evaluated for every row of the (most) outer query. And that's your other inner query, which has two rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(c) FROM t1.array_column c
       ) 
FROM (select 1 as f1, ['1', '2', '3'] as array_column
      union all
      select 2 as f1, ['5', '6', '7'] as array_column
     ) t1;
```

First, I'm surprised it works.  I thought you needed `unnest()`:

```
SELECT (SELECT STRING_AGG(c) FROM UNNEST(t1.array_column) c
       )
```

What is happening?  Well, this would be more obvious if you selected `f1`.  Then you would get:

```
1     1,2,3
2     5,6,7
```

This should make it more clear.  For each row in `t1` (and there are two rows), your code is:

- unnesting the array into rows with a column called `c`.
- reaggregating those rows into a string (with no name)

If you want to combine the elements in the arrays, use `array_concat_agg()`:

```
SELECT array_concat_agg(array_column)
FROM (select 1 as f1, ['1','2','3'] as array_column
      union all
      select 2 as f1, ['5','6','7'] as array_column
     ) t1;
```

If you want this represented as a string instead of an array, use `array_to_string()`:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_concat_agg(array_column), ',')
FROM (select 1 as f1, ['1','2','3'] as array_column
      union all
      select 2 as f1, ['5','6','7'] as array_column
     ) t1;
```

Comment: The "...For each row in t1..." helped me a lot: The inner query is executed for each line of the outer query. many Thanks.
PS: I was also surprised it worked without the `unnest`

Comment: The `unnest` was optional because the field path resolved to an array. From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#value-tables)


_In implicit unnesting, array_path must resolve to an ARRAY and the UNNEST keyword is optional_

Comment: @MassyB . . . I haven't used implicit unnesting in BigQuery.  Right now, I'm not inclined to use it, although perhaps I'll get used to it over time.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG((SELECT STRING_AGG(c) FROM t1.array_column c)) 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS f1, ['1','2','3'] AS array_column UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS f1, ['5','6','7'] AS array_column
) t1
```

and produces

```
Row f0_  
1   1,2,3,5,6,7
```

Note 1: you were almost there - you were just missing extra `STRING_AGG` that does final grouping of strings created off of respective array in each row

Note 2: because `array_column` is of ARRAY type it is treated as inner table referenced as `t1.array_column` as as such - `FROM t1.array_column c` is equivalent to `FROM UNNEST(array_column) c` - very cool `hidden` feature :o)